# where is free will located?Is it located in ahamkara or mind?

Tags: birth

Where is free will located.It is located in ahamkara or mind or ahamkara has a special capacity(freewill) When it takes birth as human.

Comment: Atma also known as jivatma is our "self", and that jivatma is what is conscious enabling us to be aware and have desires, will (free will), feelings, etc. So it's neither ahamkara nor the mind where is free will located but it is the jivatma.

Comment: it is the jivatma or it is in the jivatma

Comment: Our consciousness, awareness, desires, free will, feelings, etc, are located in the jivatma. We are that jivatma.

Answer (score 1):

Where else but the ‘Ajna chakra’ right between your eye brows - the seat of your consciousness and the ‘I’ experience. You have free will but mostly in Waking state of your consciousness. Even in Waking state, Many a times your sub-conscious mind uses it to do its things which your conscious mind does NOT notice or register. It’s like a partly shared seat required for your existence. For e.g where was your free will when you were a baby? Where is your free will when you are sleeping? How many times you scratched your hair in last 3-hrs involuntarily or  what did you do with the digested bread that you ate 1 hour ago? Questions ‘your’ conscious awareness might not be able to answer but the non- free will part like sub-conscious is aware. Question for you is can you call then your sub-conscious God? Ponder....!

Comment: In deep sleep i dont have freewill.So do you mean free will is in sukshama sarira

Comment: Even in REM sleep you don’t have free will. You don’t decide or exercise your choice selection on what to do when you dream. You just go with the flow when you dream and choices and decisions are made on your behalf.  So free will must be in the sthula sharira where you recognize the body and you are awake!